# 3d Programming with AssimpNet in MonoGame

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, assimp

I use Windows 8 and the Visual C# 2010 IDE and the latest release of MonoGame. Since MonoGame has limited support of 3d models and I want to import 3ds or Obj files, I have decided to try using AssimpNet. While importing the files I need should cause no problems(haven't tried it yet), I am at a loss of how to process the imported Scene object to render my mesh. Is there any XNA or MonoGame related site that will show how to do this and preferably deal with the matter in depth? I have search various terms in Google and failed it find any. AssimpNet's help files and file documentation either doesn't work or only will provide definitions. I am looking for a site that discusses in depth 3d programming info through C#, preferably Monogame or XNA. I cant simply use DrawModel for this. It has to be at the Matrix level.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1  "AssimpNet's help files and file documentation".  These exist?  :P

Comment: To be honest, no. I really meant Assimp's Help file. AssimpNet does ship with chm file but whatever I click on in there shows a blank page. If you are interested in model loading through AssimpNet and XNA however, check out "Render error in xna DrawPrimitive for Assimp Mesh" where I've posted most of the needed code. If you are really interested in working on this PM me at gamedev or at <anoopmalex><@><gmail.com>. Maybe we can figure this out together. I am currently working on loading material colors from an OBJ and my problem is not with my code but with blender.